# Orbits of group $G$ acting on $X$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, group-actions

Let $X=\{n \in \mathbb{N}; 1 \leq n \leq 9\}$. Let $\sigma= (123)(456)(789)$ and $\tau=(12)(34)(56)(78)$, and $G = <\sigma,\tau>$. $X$ is a $G$-set (G acts on X).

a) What is the orbit of $G$ acting on 2? What about 6? What about 8?

b) Express $|G_1|$ via $|G|$.

My solution:

I know that the orbit of an element is the set $Gx = \{gx ; g \in G\}$ therefore, we can calculate $G = \{ id, \sigma, \tau, \sigma \tau, \tau \sigma,\sigma^2 \tau , \sigma^2,\tau \sigma^2\}$ since the order of $\sigma$ is 3 and the order of $\tau$ is 2 (lcm of the length of their disjoint cycles).

Then I calculated $G = \{id, (123)(456)(789), (12)(34)(56)(78), (1354), (2463)(89),(2364)(89),(132)(465)(798),(1453)(65)(79)\} $ So 
$G2=\{2,3,1,4,3,1,2\}=\{1,2,3,4\}$. Is this correct? If yes, I will continue to do  6 and 8 similarly.

Using formula $|G|=|G1||G_1|$ I get that $|G_1|=|G| / |G1| = 8/2=4$. I don't know if this is okay...

Comment: Is this a homework problem? It sounds unnatural to pose a question formulated in this way if it were something that arose in a context other than an assignment.

Comment: @KCd I am preparing for an exam, and this is a problem I found in a book.

Comment: The orbit of $2$ is bigger than what you computed. For example, $\sigma\tau\sigma(2)=5$, so $5$ is in the orbit of $2$.

Comment: @AndreasBlass oh ok.. So my group G is not the one I calculated. Is there any other way to find each element of the orbit?

Comment: To find the orbit of some element, apply each of the generators of your group to that element, then apply each of the generators to each of the new elements you just  got, then apply each of the generators to each of the new elements you just  got, etc.  Repeat the process until you no longer get any new elements.  All the elements that you got by this process constitute the orbit of the original element.

Comment: Yes, your enumeration of $G$ is incomplete: $G$ actually has order $24$ (according to *Magma*).  For instance, $(1\ 2\ 5\ 6)(7\ 8) = \sigma \tau \sigma \in G$ as Andreas Blass points out.  Your result for $\sigma \tau$ is a little off, too; I get $\sigma \tau = (1\ 3\ 5\ 4)(7\ 9)$.